# comment='#' in pandas explanation

Tags: python, pandas, comments

Can anyone explain how comment='#' works within a csv file in pandas

```
pd.read_csv(..., comment='#',...)? Sample code is below.

# Read the raw file as-is: df1
df1 = pd.read_csv(file_messy)

# Print the output of df1.head()
print(df1.head(5))

# Read in the file with the correct parameters: df2
df2 = pd.read_csv(file_messy, delimiter=' ', header=3, comment='#')

# Print the output of df2.head()
print(df2.head())

# Save the cleaned up DataFrame to a CSV file without the index
df2.to_csv(file_clean, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how the `comment` argument works:

```
csv_string = """col1;col2;col3
1;4.4;99
#2;4.5;200
3;4.7;65"""

# Without comment argument
print(pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string), sep=";"))
#   col1  col2  col3
# 0    1   4.4    99
# 1   #2   4.5   200
# 2    3   4.7    65

# With comment argument
print(pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string), 
                  sep=";", comment="#")) 
#    col1  col2  col3
# 0     1   4.4    99
# 1     3   4.7    65
```

Comment: A bug in pandas 2.1.2: a tab or blank before the `#` --> a row `1   \t   NaN   NaN`  -- with `engine="c"` but not `engine="python"`. [Issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55916)

Answer (score 1):

You can found everything in the documentation.

Citation:

> `comment` : `str`, default `None`
>
> Indicates remainder of line should not be parsed. If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether. This parameter must be a single character. Like empty lines (as long as `skip_blank_lines=True`), fully commented lines are ignored by the parameter `header` but not by `skiprows`. For example, if `comment='#'`, parsing `#emptyna,b,cn1,2,3` with `header=0` will result in `a,b,c` being treated as the header.

Thus, it's just ignoring everything after `#` until the new line or `header`.

Comment: Thanks! I hope my noob question doesn't anger anyone haha